# Dear Community: Could you please help us by completing the site self-evaluation? Thank you!

Tags: discussion, status-completed, quality-evaluation

Good day, all.

There is currently a site self-evaluation event underway for *Personal Finance & Money*.  If you haven't already completed this evaluation, could you please help us out and review some Q & A?

The results from a site evaluation help determine if our community is ready to be [launched](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=launched) as a fully graduated site in the Stack Exchange network.

- **[Access the site self-evaluation here](https://money.stackexchange.com/review/community-eval?cb=1)**

*Thank you* for your help!

Comment: When I eval'd, I didn't rate everything a perfect, which makes me think I need to spruce up the info.  Should I wait until after the eval period so the ratings can be considered on a known baseline?  What is the SE policy?

Comment: @MrChrister IMHO, if they didn't disable editing on those posts and you see a broken window you'd like to fix, please feel free to do so.  If they don't want us doing that during the eval, I'm sure they'll let us know. :)

Comment: Yeah feel free to fix posts as you see them, @MrChrister. Y'all can do *anything* to the questions, including closing questions.

Comment: Sounds exciting :). Is the evaluation only for high rep users who have access to review function or for everyone?

Comment: @Dheer I've seen users with 101 reputation complete the review, so it is quite accessible.

Comment: Any updates on the results of evaluation? or a date when we can get the results?

Comment: @Dheer Not yet. I'm expecting Stack Exchange community folks to post the results here on meta, when they are available.

Comment: @Aarthi When/how will we find out results from the eval? Thank you.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea Since you asked, I'll write an answer to this post summarizing our analysis. :)

Comment: @Aarthi Must we wait the meme-popularized time of six to eight weeks? ;-)

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea Oh! Sorry, I just got back from vacation and I've been desperately trying to catch up on everything! I'll make a post later this afternoon.

Comment: Update: **We're next in line for graduation!**  See http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/11562316#11562316

Answer (score 8):

I'm so sorry for the delay in responding to this. We were extra-thorough in your evaluation this time around.

We agreed with your community assessment of the sample questions. The selection this time also seemed to be a better representation of your site overall. Looking at the front page of this site, there are a number of good questions at front and center, and your community has been *much* improved about closing or salvaging cruft. Furthermore, the latest crop of questions on your front page are exactly what we like to see: specific, long-tailed, and researched.

Some of us on the team are still concerned by how "drive-by" a lot of your users are. However, you all seem well aware of that (and of *why* that's the case) and are able to work with that.

Your traffic has been moving really nicely up and to the right. You've shown excellent growth for a solid year now, and your userbase and question quality is reflective of that.

### tl;dr -- Congratulations, we're putting you in the queue for graduation!

Comment: Just as an addendum: there are currently two sites ahead of Money in the graduation queue. We ask for your patience as Jin puts together design work for them as well as you.

Comment: Aarthi, this is awesome. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks Aarthi!  Time for the *budgeted* party!

Comment: Will we be having a ceremony? Cap and gown? Beer and shots?

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer actually the rabble rousing is usually done when we get  design.

Comment: Its Never to late ...

Comment: Any ETA on the graduation ... or we haven't yet put a plan in place.

Comment: @Dheer It depends on when Jin is ready to present his design, and he's got a lot of demands on his time right now. I don't have an ETA, but I assure you that y'all are not forgotten. :)

Comment: Update: **We're next in line for graduation!**  See http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/11562316#11562316